# Converting list of random floats to nearest defined set of integers

Tags: python, list, math, floating-point, set

What is the simplest/Pythonic way of converting pseudo-random float numbers to the nearest in a finite set of integer values?

For example, given values `[0.123, 2.234, 8.222]` and a `finite set {1, 2, 3}`

I want an output list of `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: What should a given value of `1.5` be mapped to?

Comment: 1.5 -> 2. This problem is akin to rounding in math simply, but to a strictly defined set - instead of an infinite linear plane.

Comment: round to even or round up?

Comment: In other words, first round all the inputs to integers, then find the closest one in the list?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Exactly this. 2 sub-problems then

Comment: Hi everyone. The solution has been solved! Someone made a response below but removed it shortly afterwards. I copied it and it works perfectly. Thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: I actually made a complete answer in native Python, but it was closed too soon from my duplicate vote! (now shown at the closing reason; it's an auto-generated comment at first)

Comment: @ti7 Although my answer got accepted, your suggestion was beautiful. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using numpy module,

```
import numpy as np

vals = [0.123, 2.234, 8.222]
ints = [1, 2, 3]

output = [ints[np.argmin([abs(x - y) for x in ints])] for y in vals]
```

may do the work. If you have sorted `ints` in descending order (`ints = [3, 2, 1]`), 1.5 would be mapped to 2.

This is less efficient (and less beautiful!) then the bisection algorithm introduced in the comment, but anyway I guess this one is easy to implement and to understand.

Comment: Thank you man :). Ty everyone